How to check if a property of an object is required or not?
What i am trying to achive is for a type that yields a boolean, provided a type and one of its key, that tells if this key in the type is required or optionam.
type MyObject = {a: 1, b?: 2}

type IsPropRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = ... // ? how to achieve this type such as

type test1 = IsPropRequired<MyObject, 'a'>      // yields true
type test2 = IsPropRequired<MyObject, 'b'>      // yields false

Playground

It looks like this playground link, see linked q/a above for more info.

@jcalz I don't think this is a duplicate. How to get from "get all required properties" to "check if a particular property is required" is not obvious, and the solution to this question is simpler than the accepted answer in the linked duplicate. Your solution is good though; I think you should post it as an answer.

That does the job just fine thank you @jcalz

@jcalz i find using this appoach playgound that uses your solution here works better for the case where is asked both a required and optional property it yields boolean
